# Symfony architecture style. Сохранение данных от сервиса: в сервисе или в Entity

Tags: архитектура, symfony

У меня в целом вопрос по тому, как "правильно" строить архитектуру.

У меня есть сущность - Product. Она имеет связанную таблицу в базе данных.

Product содержит некоторые продукты.

Есть сервис ProductFinder, задача которого собрать эти продукты из разных источников.

Метод `ProductFinder->parse():array` возвращает массив, каждый элемент которого есть экземпляр сущности `Product` с уже заполненными полями.

Теперь мне нужно для каждого элемента данного массива выполнить проверку, на некое условие и каждый экземпляр продукта сохранить в базе данных.

Вопрос такой: в каком классе будет правильным реализовать перебор элементов данного массива и сохранение их в базе данных? В классе сервиса `ProductFinder` или в классе самой сущности `Product`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из SOLID конечно вам нужно еще один сервис, который будет заниматься этим.
Более того, почти наверняка можно предположить что вас сервис ProductFinder занимается слишком многим...

Но давайте по порядку. Однозначно любую логику в модели выполнять не стоит. Вы вероятно работали с Laravel и с AR в частности, однако это не тот вариант. Короче говоря - отметаем его.

Я бы предолжил бы вам рассмотреть вариант ограничить функционал ProductFinder возвращением "сырых данных". На выходе вы сами определяете, будет это массив из ассоциативных массивов, либо это будет XML либо json в конце концов, не так уж и важно. Важно что дальше вы передаете данные сервису, который заниматеся гидрацией данных, т.е. заполнением (созданием) сущностей из ваших сырых данных, а я напомню что они могут быть не только формата array, но и чего то другого. Более того, в какой то момент вы захотите не использовать EntityManager в пользу нативной работы с базой данных, например... и получать от ProductFinder уже заполненую модель для вас будет уже не нужно...

Вот вы получили из Finder сырые данные, дальше вы можете использовать сервис реализующий интерфейс ProductCreatorInterface , например, в котором вы можете делать с данными что хотите. В частности это открывает вам путь к созданию вашей модели разными путями для различных надобностей. В этом сервисе вы занимаетесь только тем, что создаете модель из данных и используете еще сервис, реализующий интерфейс, например, ProductSaver, который на входе получает определенную модель (созданную предыдущим интерфейсом/сервисом) и на выходе сохраняет данную модель туда, куда вы захотите. В простом случае это в базу данных через EntityManager в другом случае это в базу данных через нативный SQL, а в третьем случае это и в базу данных и еще куда то одновременно.

По поводу проверки. Если дело касается непосредственно модели, то описываете валидацию на поля через аннотации к свойствам модели. Если речь идет о логике - сохранять не сохранят - то как раз в сервисе сохранения вы можете добавить в интерфейс метод ValidateMoled, и сделать отдельный сервис валидации (опять же, если речь не касается непосредственно полей).

Что вам все это дает ? Гибкость. И меру вложенности конечно же вы сами должны определять, тут нет рецепта общего.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень развернуто!

Comment: @ДмитрийСаламатов Обычно вместо спасибо ставят плюсик :)

Comment: Да, я пытался, но я по мнению сайта еще мал для этого)) Мне выводится вот такое ссобещение - "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга."